# format cout for pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

I want to convert these c code to c++ code . It is about pointer printf

```
int n = 44;
//printf("n   = %d \t &n = %x\n", n, &n);
cout<<"n ="<<n<< "\t" <<"&n ="<<hex<<int(&n)<<endl;
```

When I run the printf output is like that:

```
   n=44   &n=22ff1c
```

But when I run the cout output is like that:

```
   n=44 &n=22ff0c
```

Why do the two versions output different values for the address of n?

Comment: The hex number is the memory address of the variable. It can have different values each time you run the program.

Comment: Each time I run the printf it gives me the same answer ( &n=22ff1c). In the same way cout program gives the same result ( &n=22ff0c)

Comment: Re your edit: 2C is hex for 44.

Comment: If you want to ask another question then the correct approach is to ask a new question. The rules here are that you ask one question at a time. A second question should not be added as an edit to an earlier question, especially when it has already been answered and accepted. Please do ask a new question and I'm sure you will get a good answer.

Comment: Ok , Thank you for your advice David Heffernan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler happens to put the stack allocated variable at a different location in the different versions of the program.

Try including both printf and cout versions in the same program so that they work with the exact same pointer. Then you will see that the two versions behave the same way.

```
int n = 44;
printf("n   = %d \t &n = %x\n", n, &n);
cout<<"n ="<<n<< "\t" <<"&n ="<<hex<<int(&n)<<endl;
```

<sub>As Mr Lister correctly points out, you should use the %p format string when printing pointers in printf.</sub>

Comment: But no remarks about how you shouldn't printf a pointer by using `%x`? You guys disappoint me.

Comment: @Mr Lister fair point, was concentrating on the main point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You do not control where `n` is in memory. The compiler may change how things are positioned depending on other things that seem unrelated. It does not matter. You are not entitled to say where `n` should go; something else might already be where you want to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't mean the whitespace differences.  The address where `n` is allocated on the stack is different in each run of the program.  Otherwise, it all looks OK to me!